# Scikit-learn: RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The problem arised when I want to add another scoring method to `sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor`. To achieve this, I tried to define another regressor inheriting `HuberRegressor`. My code is shown below:

```py
class my_linear(HuberRegressor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(my_linear, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def my_score(self):
        pass

linear = my_linear(epsilon = 1.35)
linear.fit(X, y)
```

After the fit, an exception is raised: RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__ (no varargs).  with constructor (self, *args, **kwargs) doesn't follow this convention. If I delete the "*args, **kwargs" in super function, this error would not occur.

I have no idea why this error happened. Could you please explain a little bit on it and provide some possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: why do you even overload the constructor? since you don't seem to do anything other than just calling parent's constructor

Comment: @ShihabShahirar Thanks, you're right. For my purpose, I simply don't need to overload it in order to add another scoring method. But the error itself is strange to me.